# QGIS 3.22 Aggregate elements from the same layer

Tags: qgis

I have one layer that represents several land cover categories each identified thanks to a code.
I want to aggregate the number of objects each category has for a subset of code (i.e. from 111:113 how many objects do I have, from 114:222 how many objects do I have? etc.)
How can I do it from the attribute table?
I thought about the field calculator, and added the following function:

[image: aggregate]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The expression to use is:

```
count ("code_90", group_by:= "code_90" in (111,112,113))
```

*This counts the features that contain a value of 111, 112 or 113 in the field `code_90`.*

---

To automatically create a range of values (like from 114 to 222), use this expression:

```
count ("code_90", group_by:= array_contains (generate_series (114,222), "code_90" ))
```

*This counts the features that contain a value from 114 to 222.*

---

To count the number of several ranges at once, use a `CASE` condition:

```
case 
when array_contains (generate_series (111,113), "code_90" ) then count ("code_90", group_by:= array_contains (generate_series (111,113), "code_90" ))
when array_contains (generate_series (114,122), "code_90" ) then count ("code_90", group_by:= array_contains (generate_series (114,122), "code_90" ))
when array_contains (generate_series (123,133), "code_90" ) then count ("code_90", group_by:= array_contains (generate_series (123,133), "code_90" ))
when array_contains (generate_series (134,144), "code_90" ) then count ("code_90", group_by:= array_contains (generate_series (134,144), "code_90" ))
end
```

*This counts the features for the following 4 ranges: 111 to 113, 114 to 122, 123 to 133 and 134 to 144.*

---

The same, but without manually define a line for each range. Define the ranges once in line 4 inside the brackets (here 4 ranges: 111 to 113 / 114 to 122 / 123 to 133 / 134 to 144) to then get the correct count for all ranges:

```
array_max(
    with_variable (
        'list',
        'map(111,113,114,122,123,133,134,144)',
        array_foreach(
            map_akeys( eval(@list)),
            case
                when array_contains (generate_series (@element,map_get( eval(@list),@element)), "code_90" ) 
                then count ("code_90", group_by:= array_contains (generate_series (@element,map_get( eval(@list),@element)), "code_90" ))
            end
        )
    )
)
```